# How to set ekf_node in robot_localization?

Tags: robot-localization, gazebo-simulator, frame-id

What I'm currently doing is I'm trying to replace Gazebo 11 with Gazebo garden in this [document](https://navigation.ros.org/index.html). However, I ran into a problem when learning **robot_localization**.

First, I try to set **ekf_filter_node** as follows. And only read odometry information. In my understanding this could generate the conversion of odom to base_link (should be published to /tf). However, it didn't happen.

```
ekf_filter_node:
    ros__parameters:
        frequency: 30.0
    two_d_mode: false
    publish_acceleration: false
    publish_tf: true
    
    map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
    odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified

    base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" ifunspecified
    world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value ofodom_frame if unspecified

    odom0: demo/odom
    odom0_config: [true,  true,  true,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, true,
                   false, false, false]

    # imu0: demo/imu
    # imu0_config: [false, false, false,
    #               true,  true,  true,
    #               false, false, false,
    #               false, false, false,
    #               false, false, false]
```

The following is the header information of **/demo/odom**

```
header:
    stamp:
        sec: 48
        nanosec: 600000000
    frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
```

The following is tf tree
[image]

I think there should be an arrow pointing to base_link from odom in the picture. Is this understanding wrong?

Second, regarding the settings of IMU sensor data.The following sentence from the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/preparing_sensor_data.html)

> This offset is typically specified by a static transform from the base_link_frame parameter to the IMU message’s frame_id.

My understanding is that the **ekf_node** of **robot_localization** will read the **frame_id** in the imu sensor (in this example, it comes from **/demo/imu**) and convert the coordinate system to base_link according to the conversion in the tf tree. However, the **frame_id** in the data sent from Gazebo garden (Gazebosim) is as follows

```
header:
    stamp:
        sec: 1279
        nanosec: 760000000
frame_id: sam_bot/base_link/imu_sensor
```

The tf tree diagram is as above, and imu is located above imu_link. Does this mean I need to change the frame_id in the imu message to imu_link?

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question, I later found that in the launch file, I set `use_sim_time=true`, which made **ekf_node** try to subscribe to the **/clock** topic, so it is necessary to convert Gazebo’s /clock topic to the ros2 topic through the **ros_gz_bridge** package so that it can receive Time message. This also means that the time data of the sensor must match the time data of the ekf_node.

For the second question, I added an additional branch on tf_tree through tf2 static broadcast so that ekf_node can correctly find the corresponding frame.